# What might cause an IOException in Java when I make a call to Reader.read()?

Tags: java, ioexception

I have code that looks something like:

```
public static void func(Reader r){
    int c = r.read();
    ...
}
```

and the compiler tells me that [`r.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28%29) might throw an `IOException`. Under what circumstances might this happen? It seems clear that something like `FileNotFoundException` is thrown when a file is not found, but an `IOException` is rather vague.

Edit:

In case it is of interest to anyone, I asked this question because I thought there must be a better way of handling the situation than just `printStackTrace`. However, without knowing what might cause the exception, I wasn't really sure how it should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of things can cause an IOException. When it gets thrown, you can print it out or check the message (`Exception.getMessage()`) to see what caused it.

A `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`, you can check the ["known subclasses" list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) for others.

Comment: What specific situations might cause that to happen? It's just I've been using the function for a while, and I've never really seen an `IOException` being thrown before.

Comment: If the reader's underlying stream is encoded and it reads a bad chunk and pukes, if the underlying stream is a socket stream and the network dies while you're reading, if you're attempting to read from a stream that's been closed, etc. There's literally an endless number of specific instances but it will depend mostly on your specific use of `Reader.read()` and your context. In the exception handling model, it's a generic *"something with the stream is wrong"* type of exception, and obviously `read()` is a place where something can go wrong with the stream.

Answer (score 1):

It can throw an `IOException` when the either the stream itself is **corrupted** or some error occurred during reading the data i.e. Security Exceptions, Permission Denied etc and/or a set of Exceptions which are derived from `IOEXception`.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
public void load(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    this.inputStream = inputStream;
    this.properties.load(this.inputStream);
    this.keys = this.properties.propertyNames();
    inputStream.close();
}
```

I think that's when you have problem with input / output (connections) because of security or for example not opening the stream.

Code source: stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

IOException is superclass of many exceptions like CharConversionException, CharacterCodingException and EOFException.

If the method listed all these exceptions then caller would have to catch all of them. So for convenience having IOException in throws clause helps callers to avoid multiple catch blocks. User can still handle specific exception if they desire so by checking for instance of or exception.getMessage().

Comment: you can get the name of the sub-class by using System.out.println(exeption.getClass());

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the specifics, in your catch block do this:

```
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you to debug and to see the IOException thrown:

```
String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String line;
FileInputStream in;
try {
      fileName = choose.getSelectedFile().getCanonicalPath();
} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();  //This doesn't matter, see the second IOException catch.
}

try {
in = new FileInputStream(choose.getSelectedFile());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
StringBuffer content=new StringBuffer("");

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    content.append(line+NL);
}

    textArea.setText(content.toString());
    reader.close();
    reader.readLine();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "The file does not exist!", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
} catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "There was an error in reading the file.", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

Good luck.